# Outputing blocks of text in Linux based on its contents

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep, vi

I have lots of large text files that are split into grouping by known separators, { }. If a block contains a certain sequence, say xyq, then I want to output the entire block.

I know I can write a grep to get me the search tag, but how can i expand my selection to the nearest enclosing brackets?
Note, { and } can be located anywhere, ie not start or end of lines, whitespace,...

Looking for something like this :

```
Input:
 {i am a turtle}
 {i am a horse}
 {i am a programmer}

grep ???programmer??? ./File

output: {i am a programmer}
```

Comment: Can these braces nest?  `{i am {a turtle}}`?

Answer (score 1):

You could try translating the newlines into something else first. Assuming the input has no NULs, that's a good candidate.

```
cat input | tr '\n' '\0' | grep -aEo '\{.*?programmer.*?\}' | tr '\0' '\n'
```

In the regexp itself, the `?`s make the previous matches non-greedy, which means they match the shortest possible sequence instead of the longest. Note that if it's possible for the search term to occur outside of braces, this won't work right and you'll need to get more explicit:

```
cat input | tr '\n' '\0' | grep -aEo '\{[^{}]*programmer[^{}]*\}' | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Comment: @Kaz: It's a bit clearer in samples to use `cat` than it is to use the bash redirection operator.

Comment: `< input tr '\n' ... | ... | tr ... > output`

Comment: @Kaz: A lot of people won't understand what your little code snippet is doing. I don't know if the OP is one of them. It's simpler just to use `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/{\|}/ !{H; b}; /{/ {h; b open}; :open {/}/ b close; n; H; b open}; :close {g; /programmer/ p}' File
```

Explanation:

```
$ sed -n '#suppress printing of all input
> /{\|}/ !{H; b} # if no curly brackets on the line, append it to hold space and finish
> /{/ {h; b open} # if an opening { is found, copy the line to hold space and branch to label :open
> :open
> /}/ b close # if a } is matched, branch to label close
> n; H; b open # else read a new line, append it to hold space and go back to :open
> :close
> g # put all hold space to pattern space
> /programmer/ p # if _programmer_ matches, print the pattern space' File
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>cat file
 {i am a turtle}
  jay   {i am a horse}
     {i am a programmer}



>grep horse file | awk -F"{}" '{print substr($2,0,length($2)-1)}'



 i am a horse
```